# Как отобразить введенные пользователем данные в form, на отдельной странице спасибо

Tags: javascript, php, post, form, get

Подскажите, как мне отобразить данные которые пользователь ввёл в форму, на странице спасибо

такого вида код php

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST['phone'])) {
    send_the_order ($_POST);
}
function send_the_order ($post){
    $params=array(
'flow_hash' => $post['flow_hash'],
'landing' => $post['landing'],
'referrer' => $post['referrer'],
'phone' => $post['phone'],
'name' => $post['name'],
'country' => $post['country'],
'address' => $post['address'],
'email' => $post['email'],
'lastname' => $post['lastname'],
'comment' => $post['comment'],
'layer' => $post['layer'],
'sub1' => $post['sub1'],
'sub2' => $post['sub2'],
'sub3' => $post['sub3'],
'sub4' => $post['sub4'],
'sub5' => $post['sub5'],
'link_redirect' => $post['link_redirect']
);
$url = 'СЮДА ОТПРАВЛЯЮТСЯ ДАННЫЕ';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
$return= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$array=json_decode($return, true);
header('Location: thanks.php');
}
?>
```

header('Location: thanks.php'); (ВОТ СЮДА ТОЖЕ НУЖНО ОТПРАВИТЬ ДАННЫЕ, но только name и phone)
это страница спасибо на которую переходят

Если я меняю action в form на страницу thanks.php то данные приходят всё окей с помощью такого кода

```
<?=$_POST['name'];?>
<?=$_POST['phone'];?>
```

но не приходят на сервер куда нужно чтобы данные о покупатели пришли
метод формы соответственно POST

Сразу хочу попросить, не кричать, я только начинаю понимать это всё, прошу вашей помощи, я пытался искать
ответ не смог найти, возможно некорректно задаю вопрос, потому что не знаю как правильно задать

Если нужно всё уточню, всё скину.

Comment: а что значит "данные приходят на сервер"? они в базу пишутся?

Comment: Данные input они отправляются на сервер моей партнерской сети, грубо говоря кол центр, но если меняю action у формы на thanks.php то данные не приходят в этот кол центр

Comment: как работает их сервер и как принимает, честно не скажу, не знаю

Comment: думаю да, у меня есть статистика заказов в этом кол центре, значит храниться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

либо сохранить данные в сесии и после их из сесии забрать.
либо передать эти данные аргументом скрипту(я не рекомендую этот вариант)

Comment: Не дадите ссылку на инструкцию, документацию, я попробую сделать, это то что связано с сессиями это Django?
И передача данных аргументом, тоже как пример небольшой, если не сложно можно?